# Windows 11 + PHP + Imagick issue with second browser window and timeout

Tags: php, xampp, imagick

I have a PHP script that modify images using ImageMagick and the script runs for a very long time. Now I want to start a second PHP script while the first script is running, which also processes images, but this script loads dead and breaks after 30s and do nothing. ImageMagick is responsible for this. As soon as I call `$image = new Imagick;` in second PHP script this script is on hold and waits until script 1 is finished. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to solve it for Windows? I use here Xampp with PHP 8.1 on Windows 11. Maybe a stupid question, but I have not found anything on this.

script 1
`<?php $image = new Imagick; sleep(10); ?>`

script 2
`<?php $image = new Imagick; ?>`

Start both scripts and script 1 block imagick for 10s, so script 2 is waiting 10s to finish.

Comment: Are you using PHP sessions?

Comment: @hakre No. The second file have only this content `<?php $image = new Imagick; ?>` there are no sessions. ;)

Comment: So the first file has a session? Perhaps session auto start then? Why I ask is b/c there is file-locking with sessions. Now sessions must not be there, but other file-locking might be in effect, so that you run into a so called [_race-condition_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), which can happen with file lockings (and other things) when you're dealing with shared resources. Check if you try to do something on the same file for example.